# Database linked with Java program without server

Tags: java, database

I have this java program that reads values from a database, and uses those values in each table for creating a schedule.

I do not have a server accessible, so the database will have to be moved around from computer to computer when the program is moved. It will have about 200 tables, each one with a time, number, title, and description.

I have tried using Microsoft Access, but Java 8 just changed some setting so that the program cannot link the Access database, even though there used to be a simple way to do this.

I know about Java DB, but to my knowledge it needs a server to host the database on, same with SQL, and I do not have one to use.

My question is, which program can I use to create a client-side database that can be linked with a java program, without breaking off an arm and a leg.

Thank You for any suggestions.

Comment: You could use an embedded database like [Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/).

Comment: Here is an [SQLite Tutorial for Java](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm).

Comment: "It will have about 200 tables, each one with a time, number, title, and description." I hope you mean rows, not tables.

Comment: info: embedded database like Derby will have only one concurrent connection.

Comment: @Joeblade What i meant was relating to the way Microsoft Access works, with a table having multiple rows (classes), each one having a time, name, title, description. Since Access is the only way I can relate to a database, yes, 200 tables.

Comment: Ok in relational databases you'll find that people will use the term table for a group of rows that all share the same structure. if that's the case then wow :) that's quite a large structure. I would have rather expected it to be a single table with 200 rows inside.

Comment: @Joeblade Yeah, it is a very large structure. Filling it will take quite a while, and its due soon, so I'll be looking into Derby and sqlite shortly, thank you to everyone for the suggestions :).